# How to exclude files in torrent from download?

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

Is it possible to exclude certain files within a torrent from downloading using the Transmission client? I can't seem to be able to find any such option. If I go to Properties → Files, there are no options whatsoever.

I used to use this feature regularly in BitTorrent on Windows.

Comment: How are you downloading the torrent? I believe if you're using a magnet URL, you don't get to choose what's downloading, but if you open a `.torrent` file in Transmission, you can get to choose what files to download within the torrent.

Comment: @AlaaAli You can choose what files to download in a torrent started via magnet URL, you just have to wait until Transmission has retrieved tracking information and knows what files comprise the torrent. By the time anything is actually downloading, files can be deselected in the torrent properties.

Comment: @Eliah aaah I remember doing something like that once. I might post an answer with screenshots.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it is posible.

Open transmision ->Click on the torrent you wish to edit -> Afther you click, you have on transmision top bar a button called `Properties` click on it.

A new windows should appear
On that windows you have a tab called `Files` click on it
In this tab you should see some checkboxes, **if you cannot see the ckeckboxes,resize the windows and make it bigger.**

Comment: I feel so stupid right now XD! I switched from a 1400x900 laptop to a 1366x768 laptop, on the new screen, the resolution forced the checkboxes to be hidden to the right of the window border.

Comment: Wow! Didn't realize long file names were pushing the checkboxes out of the window.  Alternative to resizing the window, resizing the *Name* column also does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

### If downloading from a magnet URL:

Leave it to download the metadata:

[image]

Once it's done with the metadata and says "Downloading from peers":

> Right click the torrent → Properties → Files tab

Deselect what you don't want it to download.

[image]

### If downloading from a `.torrent` file:

You should find the selection as soon as you add the `.torrent` file, before starting the download.

Answer (score 2):

In Transmission, right-click on the torrent and click Properties.

[image]

In the torrent's properties dialog, click the Files tab.

[image]

You can uncheck files in the Downloads column.

- If the torrent has a folder structure, you can check and uncheck whole folders too.
- If some but not all files appear, perhaps the torrent has a folder structure and not all folders are expanded. You can expand them with the **+** icon to the left of the folder name.
- If not files appear at all, **you probably added the torrent via magnet link and it hasn't retrieved any tracking information yet**. Tracking information has to be received in order for any data transfer between you and other peers, so once anything begins downloading, the files will appear and can be unchecked.