# Why isn't there any uTorrent desktop client available for Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, bittorrent, utorrent

I am using **Deluge BitTorrent Client** in **Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS** for handling torrents. I wanted uTorrent Desktop Client (like uTorrent for Windows); I searched couple of times but only found [this way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104094/how-to-install-utorrent-step-by-step) of installing the uTorrent server. Am I correct to assume that there is no uTorrent Desktop Client available for Ubuntu (post-14.04 releases included)?

**Edit:** if so, why? Does the Linux environment not allow it OR the developers didn't make it?

Comment: That's right, there's no uTorrent desktop client for GNU/Linux.

Comment: but why do you want to use u/BitTorrent on Linux? Transmission or qBittorrent are much better and totally ad-free.

Comment: It's not that I want to use u/BitTorrent only... I only wanted to know what's best & functional in GNU/Linux; Yes, I have tried Transmission but it doesn't allow choosing specific files while downloading (also some other features that I use in uTorrent while on Windows)... I am using Deluge for now; will try qBittorrent if Deluge fails.  AND @ViBE CAN YOU EXPLAIN HOW qBitorrent BETTER THAN uTorrent OTHER THAN THE FACT THAT qBitorrent IS AD-FREE?

Comment: Transmission definitely supports choosing specific files out of a torrent. It'll ask you as soon as you provide it the .torrent file.

Comment: @amanthethy can you provide screenshot(s)?

Comment: @NileshGupta I'm not at my Ubuntu machine right now, but if you open any .torrent file, transmission will open up to the file selection pane automatically. If you're opening .magnet files, the files selection pane won't show up. You can change your selections by right-clicking the download in transmission, selecting properties and then clicking on the tab labeled "Files".

Comment: @amanthethy okay, I got it now that Transmission(unlike uTorrent) doesn't download metadata while the files selection pane is open.

Comment: @ViBE do tell...

Comment: @NileshGupta i changed to qBittorrent about 3 years ago so i'm not sure uTorrent how changed. but i can tell you why did i switch to it:
1.) cross-platform
2.) no adware in the installer
3.) eats less CPU
4.) ad-free nice GUI
5.) perfect search engine.

and why cross-platform important? cause i'm use Windows too and under Ubuntu i can easily access my NTFS drive's downloads and continue any transfer. that's all i can tell now. you may check this little article: http://www.maximumpc.com/best-torrent-software-2015/

Comment: @NileshGupta and yes you right. Transmission cannot download metadata yet so no way to select content if you got only a magnet link. with torrents it works fine.

Comment: You can always go to the properties of a torrent in Transmission and deselect individual files for download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right, there's no µTorrent desktop client for GNU/Linux. (see the [official download page](http://www.utorrent.com/intl/en/downloads/linux))

Alternatives are to use a [Wine environment](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=6824) to run µTorrent for Windows or a native Torrent client like [Transmission](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/transmission/) or Deluge. More clients are available through the Software Center with the search term "torrent".

Comment: I read Wine has some "can't find downloaded content" related problems;   I have tried both & using Deluge for now; I DON'T THINK uTorrent RUNNING ON Wine WOULD BE BETTER THAN THE NATIVE Transmission OR Deluge??

Comment: That's primarily opinion-based. The test reports in the Wine AppDB for µTorrent are very mixed and rarely above “silver”, meaning some feature is missing. I'm happy with Transmission; it provides detailed per-torrent configuration options, a daemon mode with various (remote) interfaces and uses the least system resources (of all tested Torrent clients according to their benchmarks).

Answer (score 0):

Transmission has the best GUI, but it is a little low on options. For linux I would suggest [ktorrent](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/ktorrent/) which with the media player plugins allows for sequential downloads: i.e. watching videos before they complete the download (non copyright ones offcourse). Even µTorrent only does this for paying users.

Both allow you to select individual files - see here for [Transmission](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517157/how-to-exclude-files-in-torrent-from-download)(but be aware that the file will download with the sector it is in - so you might get more than just that file).

p.s.
QBittorrent also does that- So i would also recommend it.

Comment: uTorrent allows streaming while downloading media files even for non-paying users, although it's kind of a workaround involving VLC and stream URLs.

Comment: Well it is 6 button clicks in QBitTorrent...

Comment: You can also see how to download individual files from Trasminssion in the link - even for magnet...

Comment: the workaround in uTorrent doesn't require any clicks...just some keyboard shortcuts

Comment: provide the link for downloading individual files from magnet link in Trasminssion

Comment: Check the second answer of the link:http://askubuntu.com/questions/517157/how-to-exclude-files-in-torrent-from-download

Comment: I knew that already; I thought it would say how to select files to download before starting the torrent but that's not possible since Transmission(unlike uTorrent) doesn't download metadata while the files selection pane is open after clicking the magnet link.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to download seperate file in a torrent.
Open Transmission, click on the torrent, go to the Properties tab and choose only the file (files) you want.
If the uploader did their job correctly, the majority do, the torrent should not be only one file but an amalgamation of seperate, smaller, files.
But, if you have the bandwidth to spare, do everyone a favor and download everything so you can be a node.