# Transmission web client file properties

Tags: server, transmission

Ok so this question will be very similar to this one: [How to exclude files in torrent from download?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517157/how-to-exclude-files-in-torrent-from-download)

However, this is not the same question. In this question, I am wondering how you should go about following the solution mentioned in the linked question (Going into properties and choosing files) within the transmission web client as I cannot see a way to access properties from within the web client.

Thank you

Comment: I usually right-click on the torrent in progress.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a solution but not quite an answer, a work around.

The transmission Qt Client for windows has this feature but of course is not the web client.

https://transmissionbt.com/